# Add a new column that shows the name of another column with minimum value (+ condition)

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a following dataframe:

```
a  b  c  d
3  5  7  11
7  5  11 13 
11 13 7  17 
11 13 17 19
```

I would like to add another column that  for each row gives the name of the column with a minimal value... as long as the minimal value is lower than 11 (otherwise, leave blank).
The final result would be:

```
a  b  c  d  e
3  5  7  11 a
7  5  11 13 b 
11 13 7  17 c 
11 13 17 19
```

I know how I can get the column with a minimum value for each row:

```
df.idxmin(axis=1)
```

I also know how to get the minimum value:

```
df.min(axis=1)
```

When I am trying to get it done in a one-liner:

```
df['e'] = df.idxmin(axis=1) if df.min(axis=1) < 11 else ''
```

I get the error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `where` to filter values.

```
df['e'] = df.idxmin(axis=1).where(df.min(axis=1) < 11)
```